# How to decide if a function is increasing (strictly) at point where derivative is zero

Tags: calculus

It is easy enough to formally prove that $f(x) =x^3$ is increasing even when its derivative at $x=0$ is $0$ but what about some complex function,  say the polynomial $g(x)=
(3/2)x^4-3x^2+1$? Is it increasing,  decreasing or neither at $x=-1, 0,1$? (where its derivative is $0$). If it is increasing or decreasing then what is the meaning of zero rate of change of $y$ wrt $x$ in this case?

Please answer a bit rigorously even though I am taking Calculus.

Comment: When a function's derivative equals $0$ for some $x$, then that function has a local minimum/maximum at that $x$. So it's neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: Man what about y=x^3 at x=0

Comment: @IncludedExcluded actually, you're correct. What is true, though, is that **if**  $f$ has an extremum at $x$ and is differentiable at this point, $f'(x) = 0$. The converse is not true as shown by your example.

Answer (score 2):

The notion "increasing" always refers to *pairs of points*: A function $f$ is *increasing* in the interval $J$ if for all $x<y$ in $J$ we have $f(x)\leq f(y)$, and is *strictly increasing* if for all $x<y$ in $J$ we have $f(x)< f(y)$. Therefore it makes no sense to ask whether a function "is increasing at $x=0$".

Now a familiar criterion for "increasing" is the sign of the derivative $f'$. One proves: If $f$ is differentiable in the interval $J$ then $f$ is increasing in $J$ iff $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in J$, and is strictly increasing iff for all $x\in J$ one has $f(x)\geq0$  **but**  in no subinterval of positive length $f(x)\equiv0$.

Isolated zeros of the derivative therefore do not destroy the monotonicity of $f$.

Comment: a function is increasing at a point x=a if there exists an interval (a-§, a+§)  such that function is increasing at that interval. What I asked is the proof of precisely what you have stated about non zero derivative of positive length.

Answer (score 0):

Keep taking derivatives until the first non-zero derivative at the point of interest. So for $x^3$:

$$f'(x)=3x^2$$
$$f''(x)=6x, f''(0) = 0$$

$x^3$ is peculiar, it has an inflection point here so take another derivative.

$$f'''(x) = 6, f'''(0) = 6$$
So, $x^3$ is an increasing function at $x=0$.

$g(x)$ next:

$$g'(x) = 6x^3 - 6x$$

As you already figured, at $-1$, $0$, and $1$, the first derivative is 0. Take another derivative:

$$g''(x) = 18x^2 - 6$$

$g''(0) = -6$ which means it curves down, it is a decreasing function at this point. $g''(-1) =g''(1) = 12$. It curves up at these points so it is increasing. If you plot $g(x)$ you can see this is true.

This has nothing to do with 'monotonically increasing' which is where it has to be increasing everywhere as in the $x^3$ function.

Comment: As stated, the question does not assume $f$ to be continuously differentiable, or even differentiable at more than one point. I think it'd be nice if you could add that you're taking $f \in C^\infty$.

Comment: Wait how do you justify your steps? Why keep on taking derivatives? I know its the nth derivative test but dont know why it makes sense...

Comment: When the 1st derivative is zero, the second derivative tells you if it curves 'up'. When the second derivative is zero, the third derivative tells you if the second derivative curves 'up' as $x$ increases. I could do this ad nauseam. As @Guido points out, this works as long as the function has these derivatives.

Comment: So if the third derivative tells that second derivative curves up,  then what does it tell about the original function. Also what is the meaning of zero derivative if function is increasing at that point?

Comment: It literally means it is horizontal at that point. But if the second derivative is positive, then any small increment in the positive $x$ direction means the 1st derivative increases. Since the 1st derivative is zero and increases it must be positive for any small increment. Therefore, the function increases even though it is horizontal at this point.

Comment: Yes I get it intuitively but i dont think it is rigorous enough.  I guess it can wait till Analysis.

Comment: I get that it increases after x=0 but what about "at" x=0