# Why is $x$ increasing on part of an interval where $f'(x)$ is zero?

Tags: calculus

In the below image, the author includes the point on which $f'(x)=0$ as part of the region on which $f$ is increasing. I am wondering why this is the case, as the derivative being zero at a point means that there is no increase at that point. The points in question are $x= \sqrt{2/3}$, and the negative of this.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2807247/42969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x)$ has critical points at $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. For $x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}]\cup [\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\infty)$, $f^\prime(x)>0$ suggesting that function is increasing. In particular, strictly increasing. When $x\in [-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}]$, $f^\prime(x)<0$ and so the function is decreasing. The function plotted is $f^\prime(x)$. The endpoints at $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ are included since $f(x)$ is a continuous function and extending the function to a point wher $f^\prime(x)=0$ will still ensure the function is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

To be strictly increasing on an interval $I$, the function $f$ must satisfy

$$ b > a \implies f(b) > f(a) $$

for all $a,b \in I$. If the function has zero derivative on all of some sub-interval $J$, then this won't be true, as expected. This is because $f$ is constant on an interval where its derivative is zero, and so any $a,b\in J$ has $f(a) = f(b)$.

However, if there are just isolated points where the derivative is zero, and the derivative is positive everywhere else, then the function will still be strictly increasing. This is because any interval $[a,b]$ will have some intervals containing only positive derivatives, contributing to the increase of the function, while there are no points with negative derivatives to counter those contributions in any way; the points with zero derivative have no contribution in either direction.

So, in your given example, you're allowed to include those isolated points at $\pm \sqrt{2/3}$ in the intervals without robbing them of being strictly increasing, because they have positive derivatives everywhere else.